# Kaspersky identifying /posts/popup/anon-vote as phishing

Tags: support, bug, status-bydesign, blocked, malicious-code

I tried to upvote the below question before hitting refresh, so I got the anonymous vote popup - but Kaspersky blocks it:

[image]

After allowing it:

[image]

Comment: Perhaps this should be reported to Kaspersky instead? Not sure what can be done about overzealous AV programs on this side of the fence.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Perhaps SE staff should report it to them? Or alter the code that's tripping it. I've had Kaspersky installed for about 18 months - this is the first time I've ever had a phishing warning.

Comment: @MartijnPieters the report would carry more weight if it came from SE staff. They could even show the code that was generating the popup.

Comment: @ChrisF: perhaps; but it is not as if the code isn't available to Kaspersky. And if the team had to reach out to every AV and firewall and router vendor out there that could potentially screw up the experience they'd never get to the actual features we want them to hack on instead.

Comment: @MartijnPieters there is that. But if I were Kaspersky I'd take more notice if the site developers contacted me than a random user.

Comment: @MartijnPieters So instead, non-tech-savvy people will **never** get to the feature they need (this was on Cooking.SE), let alone get *new* features - i.e. I think your analogy is flawed. I agree with ChrisF, which is why I posted this question in the first place.

Comment: There is also a possibility that there is some form of redirection on the client machine, not with the site code, tripping something. First you have to determine where the trigger is coming from.

Comment: @BartSilverstrim I can help you with this if you let me know what you want me to do? On the second screenshot, you'll see the URL affected in the Kaspersky dialog.

Comment: I never liked Kaspersky. Now I know why.

Comment: @DannyBeckett they are much better at offence than defense though. :-D

Comment: NOT... ENOUGH... OPEN TABS.  MUST... CTRL-CLICK... AGAIN...

Comment: @Won't Lol, I just closed about 25

Comment: prohibiting anonymous voting is a clear sign of totalitarian system

Answer (score 2):

We aren't able to control how the Kaspersky checks operate.  If anyone has contacts with them I'd be glad to follow up.

Comment: I have a good contact there if you can give me an email address or somewhere private to send you her email?